# Insert new interface method namespace Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, javascript-namespaces

I am working with a third-party library that has a namespace `thisLibrary` and within that namespace has an interface `Options`. I would like to add a property to the `Options` interface and then use the update version of `Options` within my code. The `index.d.ts` file for the library looks like this:

```
export = thisLibrary;
export as namespace thisLibrary;

declare function thisLibrary(elements: HTMLElement | HTMLElement[], options: thisLibrary.Options): void;

declare namespace thisLibrary {
   const propA: boolean;
   let propB: number;

   interface Options{
      list?: ListEntry[] | any[];
      propC?: string;
      propD?: string | number;
   }
}
```

I would like to be able to import `thisLibrary` into my code and then add typing for `propE?: boolean` such that I can pass `propE` into my function call for `thisLibrary` and not raise errors.

I'm working within an Angular framework, and my code looks like this:

```
import * as thisLibrary from 'thisLibrary';

export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
   constructor() {}

   ngOnInit(): void {
      this.doThis()
   }

   private doThis(): void { 
      const myHTML = this.getHTML()
      thisLibrary(myHTML, {
         list: [[a, 10], [b, 7]],
         propC: 'blah blah',
         propD: 10,
         propE: true
      }
   }
```

At the moment, this code throws an error in my TS linter because `propE` "does not exist in type Options".

Comment: Start with `declare module 'thisLibrary' { namespace thisLibrary { interface Options … } }`?

Comment: Prior to the import? If so, I just tried this, and the type for `propE` is still undeclared.

Comment: Shouldn't matter where you declare it, but I think that's the syntax for declaration merging.